# Why UTF-8 contents not displayed in a servlet deployed in jetty?

Tags: servlets, utf-8, jetty-9

I am trying to test a Servlet with special character which is deployed in jetty 9.
I am posting a String with a single quote character to the Servlet. Though I have mentioned to use UTF-8 character encoding in the Servlet , the Servlet cannot print the single quote character. I don't know what's wrong in the following code :

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class SpecialCharacterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


}
```

The main method

```
public static void main(String s[]) {
        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8080/test/SpecialCharacterServlet").openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=*****");

            String str = "Hello ‘World’";
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(str);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] content = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(content);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

The output does not show the single quoted  character , the output is `Hello World` , it's some block in there .

Comment: What does the documentation of DataOutputStream.writeBytes() say? Does it say that it uses UTF8 to encode the characters? What does the documentation of the InputStreamReader constructor say? Does it say that it decode bytes using UTF8?

Comment: I used ` request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` , that doesn't help , there is a function  'DataOutputStream.writeUTF(str)'  , that does the task , thank you so much

Comment: Read the javadoc of setCharacterEncoding(). It has an effect on how getParameter() and getReader() work. But since you transform bytes in the request body in characters using your own InputStreamReader, that can't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove any action where character sets are implied but not defined.

1. Ensure that you're Main.class is UTF-8 encoded.
2. Ensure that javac is aware that Main.class is UTF-8 encoded. Most IDE's do this for you but it requires you to set the encoding in the file properties
3. In `main()` wrap the OutputStream with OutputStreamWriter with an explicit charset declaration. This ensures everything written through the OutputStreamWriter is in the correct charset:

   ```
   osw = OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
   osw.write(str);
   ```
4. In your servlet, tell your inputStream to decode from "UTF-8":

   ```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
   ```
5. System.out is also subject to charset conversion. This is particularly troublesome on DOS consoles. Instead, write the result to a text file and check the results in a good text editor, such as Notepad++. Again, when writing to the text file, set the character set in the constructor of your writer.